# Supabase nested join table query issue

Tags: next.js, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I have 2 tables

```
users: {
   id, 
   name
}

friends: {
   id,
   requestSentBy: relation(users_id), 
   requestSentTo: relation(users_id)
}
```

and what i want to achieve is get the user table with all friends table joined wherever his id is in either requestSentBy or requestSentTo table using supabase

My current query looks like this

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
          .from('users')
          .select(
            '*, friends!friends_requestSentBy_fkey(*)'
          )
          .eq('id', user?.id);
```

But this would exclude rows where requestSentTo has user id

**Edited**

I want to query the friends table as a join to my users profile data
So the output would look something like this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "user_id": 1,
      "name": "John Doe",
      "friends": [
            {
                  "friend_id": 1,
                  "requestSentBy": 1,
                  "requestSentTo": 2,
            },
            {
                  "friend_id": 2,
                  "requestSentBy": 4,
                  "requestSentTo": 1,
            }
       ],
    }
  ],
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK"
}
```

In hint i got this as a response:

"Try changing 'friends' to one of the following: 'friends!friends_requestSentBy_fkey', 'friends!friends_requestSentTo_fkey'. Find the desired relationship in the 'details' key."

The following query works

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
          .from('users')
          .select('*, posts(*), friends!friends_requestSentBy_fkey(*)')
          .eq('id', pathname.split('/')[2])
          .single();
```

But only returns those friends whom the user had sent request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution.

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
   .from('users')
   .select('*, to:friends!friends_requestSentTo_fkey(*), sent:friends!friends_ requestSentBy_fkey(*)')
```

Found the solution here [Github Question](https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/13035)

Answer (score 0):

That query doesn't look correct. Let me give an example for you:

**This is your tables:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
   user_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE friends (
   friend_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   requestSentBy INT,
   requestSentTo INT,
   FOREIGN KEY (requestSentBy) REFERENCES users(user_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (requestSentTo) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);
```

*Note: `requestSentBy` and `requestSentTo` are linked to `user_id` in the `users` table.*

**Your query should be like this:**

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('friends')
  .select(`
    friend_id,
    from:requestSentBy(name),
    to:requestSentTo(name)
  `)
```

**Output:**

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "friend_id": 1,
      "from": {
        "name": "Deep Shetye"
      },
      "to": {
        "name": "Emre"
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK"
}
```

[More detail in Supabase Docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response.

Actually i found the solution. My question was slightly different.
I wanted to know what if we wanted to start from users table and then query their friends.

Comment: Sorry. I'm glad you found the solution @DeepShetye.